# Bidirection routing with openvpn between two subnets

Tags: routing, openvpn

I am new to openvpn and recently I setup an openvpn in my network(all systems have centos):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3Y13.jpg)

OpenVpn computer has a direct connection (through one of its interfaces) to subnet 192.168.2.0/24 and client 10.8.0.2 is connected to vpn server with openvpn client. Now I want to make bidirectional connection between client 10.8.0.2 to subnet/server 192.168.2.3 . How is it possible?

My server.config file is:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
user nobody
group nobody
persist-key
persist-tun
keepalive 10 120
topology subnet

server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0


ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "dhcp-option DNS 1.0.0.1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 1.1.1.1"
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
dh none
ecdh-curve prime256v1
tls-crypt tls-crypt.key 0
crl-verify crl.pem
ca ca.crt
cert server_uePSv7FhLjJEF4mf.crt
key server_uePSv7FhLjJEF4mf.key
auth SHA256
cipher AES-128-GCM
ncp-ciphers AES-128-GCM
tls-server
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-cipher TLS-ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256
status /var/log/openvpn/status.log
verb 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to inform the openvpn client that the route exists, so add this line to your server's openvpn config:

```
push "route 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0"
```

That should be enough, assuming you don't block this forwarding via iptables (allow it with e.g. `iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun0; iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0` assuming `eth0` is your 192.168.2.0/24 interface and `tun0` is the openvpn interface) and have forwarding enabled via e.g. `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

This is not really routing between two subnets as the title suggests, this is routing between a host and a subnet. If the client was in fact a gateway to e.g. 192.168.8.0/24 then you would also need these lines in your server's openvpn config:

```
route 192.168.8.0 255.255.255.0
client-config-dir ccd
```

Put this in `/etc/openvpn/ccd/clientname`:

```
iroute 192.168.8.0 255.255.255.0
```

Now the openvpn server will add a route to 192.168.8.0/24 whenever that client connects.

Comment: Thank you @wurtel for your help. I did all your instructions,It forwards to websites but still I can't ping one of the computers in 192.168.2.0/24 range(local network)

Comment: Does the computer you are pinging have the openvpn server as its gateway? If not then the response packets aren't routed back to the openvpn client. Adding a route for the openvpn client IP range via the openvpn server to the computer should help (you could also add that route to the default gateway, that will then send icmp redirects to the correct gateway).